# is my bacon cooked?

Tags: food-safety, bacon

I cut up 1 lb of bacon and cook it for 30 min, at the 10 min mark I add sausage and at 20 mins some vegetables, it looks soggy just wondering if it is cooked?

Comment: Cook it how? On a pan or in the oven? What temp? Was the bacon spread evenly without overlap, or stacked in a pile?

Comment: It's difficult for sure to know if it's cooked based on your description.  Bacon can be considered fully cooked and still be limp / soggy.  But some people have psychological issues if you try to serve it to them like that, as their mind tells them it's unsafe and they need to avoid it.  (my mom's bacon-lined terrine one christmas didn't go over so well)

Answer (score 1):

It's cooked.

You added some vegetables, the vegetables will release tons of liquid/moisture making everything soggy.